# why does SearchDelegate buildSuggetions not let me use a stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been trying to get this working for 2 hours now. For some reason a stateful widget won't update the query other than the first letter. This is the little code I have.

```
...
    @override
      Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
        if(this.query.length > 0) {
          return Test(search: this.query,);
        }
        return Container();
      }
...
```

and then in the stateful widget Test:

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  final String search;
  Test({Key key, this.search}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState(search);

}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  String search;
  _TestState(this.search);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(search);
  }
}
```

Comment: `_TestState(search)` do not use such constructor - use `_TestState createState() => _TestState();` and `widget.search` inside `_TestState`

Comment: Changing the constructor didn't work. Trying State.didUpdateWidget but not sure if I'm doing it right. `@override
  void didUpdateWidget(PromotionLazyLoad oldWidget){
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    search = widget.search;
  }` (PromotionLazyLoad is like the function in my question above)

Comment: what didnt work? did you really use `widget.search` in your state? use both `Test` and `YourTest` inside `buildSuggestions` method like here: https://pastebin.com/jSn6Ch7P

Comment: Yes, I did try both like you did in that example (but not at the same time). What do you mean I should use both Test and YourTest though? In your example it looks like you're only using Test in your buildSuggestions

Comment: and which one worked: `Test` or `YourTest`?

Comment: did you try to `print` passed search string inside `build` method in both classes, like `print('YourTest, this.query: [$query] widget.query: [${widget.query}]');` and `print('Test, widget.query: [${widget.query}]');`? if so, what do you see?

Comment: None seemed to work. I'll try that once I get home and update (thanks for the help so far btw)

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot for the help!!! Had just missed a tiny detail with the didUpdateWidget thing that you suggested!